# Savings account in UK but working and living in the EU

Tags: non-resident, savings-account

Is there any reason not to have a bank or savings account in the UK even though I live and work in Germany? I'm a UK citizen. Is the tax situation awkward if the savings account earns interest?

Comment: Typically banks subtract the tax from the interest they give you, so I think it would be a complication for you to ask your bank not to do it. Legally you should pay tax on your global income in the country you reside in, although not advice, do you really care that some small amount goes into UK taxes rather than German ones? Worse case I can think of is that German tax office finds out about it and asks you to pay the taxes on that interest. If your bank doesn't already pay the tax for you, then you'd have to declare the profits in Germany and pay the tax on them